# Sending GET request for an SQL query with parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, express, http

Let me start by giving you some context. I'm using Angular for the frontend of the application and express for the backend, and I'm only learning how to use them both.

I have a parent component that creates a group (child component) for every customer on a list of customers, and each group has some location child components; that is to say, the locations are grouped by customer. The problem is that I'm trying to send an HTTP GET request (that has the customer id attached to it) from each of the group components to get a list of all locations that correspond to said customer. I know that sending parameters or a body with a GET request is a bad practice, so it not only doesn't work but I also need to find a different way to do it.

The code below represents the structure of my application on the most simplified way possible, having removed everything that is not related with the problem:

**Angular component:** gets instantiated several times on a parent component using an ngFor.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'group-locations',
  templateUrl: './group-locations.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./group-locations.component.css']
})
export class GroupLocationsComponent {

  private locationService = inject(LocationService);

  locationsArray: WritableSignal<Location[]> = signal([]);

  @Input()
  customerItem!: Customer; //this customer item has an id_customer property.

  getLocations(idCustomer: number): void {
    this.locationService.getLocations(idCustomer).subscribe(locationsReturned => 
      this.locationsArray.set(locationsReturned)
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getLocations(this.customerItem.id_customer);
  }
}
```

**LocationService:** sends the HTTP requests to the backend.

```
export class LocationService {

  private httpClient = inject(HttpClient);

  url: string = this.router.getRoute(); //don't worry about this, I removed the imports for simplicity's sake, just know the url is correct.

  getLocations(idCustomer: number): Observable<Location[]> {

     const locationsArrayObservable = this.httpClient.get(url, {id_customer: idCustomer}) as Observable<Location[]>; //this doesn't work, it's just to give you and idea of what I'm trying to do.

     return locationsArrayObservable;
   }
}
```

**Express route:** the part on the backend that processes the request.

```
let locationRouter: Router =  express.Router();

async function getLocationsByCustomer(req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction) {
    try {

        let idCustomer = req.body.id_customer; //trying to get the idCustomer that the frontend passed when the request was created.

        let result = await runQueryAsync(`select * from dbo.locations where id_customer = ${idCustomer};`); //this comes from a db service that just runs queries and nothing else.
        
        res.json(result.recordset);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Error executing query`);
        next(err);
    }
}

locationRouter.get('/', getLocationsByCustomer);

export { locationRouter };
```

Any ideas on how to make this work or suggestions on a different way of doing it?

Comment: Don't use `GET` request bodies. They are unreliable. I wrote some notes about this here: https://evertpot.com/get-request-bodies/ and you can read the question I asked about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: @Evert I read your question and some articles about why not to use GET bodies before resorting to asking, hence why I mentioned that I was looking for an alternative way of doing this. I'm looking into maybe parsing the parameters I need on the url but I'm not sure if it'll work since I need to send a request for each customer and the number of customers changes. If that works I'll post an answer

Comment: Hey, in that case... why not just use something other than `GET`. `QUERY` probably best, and should be pretty well supported. If not, use `POST`.

Comment: @Evert I ended up using query params on the GET request's url and it works flawlessly. I'll post an answer later. Not sure if you were refering to the same _query_ but thanks for the idea still :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the way I ended up making it work was using params on the url when sending the request, it goes as follows:

**LocationService:**

```
export class LocationService {

  private httpClient = inject(HttpClient);

  url: string = this.router.getRoute();

  getLocations(idCustomer: number): Observable<Location[]> {

    let queryParams = new HttpParams().append('idCustomer', idCustomer); // <-- right here

    const ubicacionesArrayObservable = this.apiService.getRequest(`${this.url}/p/`, {params: queryParams}) as Observable<Ubicacion[]>; // <-- and also here

    return locationsArrayObservable;
   }
}
```

**Express route:**

```
let locationRouter: Router =  express.Router();

async function getLocationsByCustomer(req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction) {
    try {

        let idCustomer = req.query.idCustomer; // <-- here I extract the params

        let result = await runQueryAsync(`select * from dbo.locations where id_customer = ${idCustomer};`);
        
        res.json(result.recordset);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Error executing query`);
        next(err);
    }
}

locationRouter.get('/p/', getLocationsByCustomer);

export { locationRouter };
```